# Where are transaction fees specified?

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees

I've recently looked up the exact format of a transaction and came up with this ([source with explanation](https://betterprogramming.pub/the-bitcoin-script-language-e4379908448f)):

[image]

However, this seems not to include transaction fees. Are they not part of the transaction? Or do they have a special output lock script that basically makes it available to everybody?

Answer (score 5):

The transaction fee is implicitly specified. It is given to the miner as the remainder of the transaction: the difference between the sum of all transaction inputs and the sum of all transaction outputs is left free to be collected by the miner.

See also:
[collecting block reward and transaction fees](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/80784/collecting-block-reward-and-transaction-fees?rq=1)